# Transition of first item in WinRT ListView

Tags: listview, animation, windows-runtime, transition

I am facing an issue that I have encountered several times before but I never found a universal solution. If create a basic ListView in Windows 8.1 WinRT and set it's ItemsSource through a Binding expression to a list of plain strings for example, when the page is first loaded or when the list is assigned to a new collection, the transition of the first item in the ListView is not smooth - it is animated either a bit sooner or later than it should. All other items fly in in a nice "staggered" manner, but the first item is always a bit out of place.
I am encountering this problem in many apps around and I would love to know if someone has a tried and tested way to prevent this behavior or a way to explain why it is happening.

Here is some sample code:

```
<Page
x:Class="App1.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App1"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
x:Name="Page"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">Rebind random</Button>
    <ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Data, ElementName=Page}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="400" Height="100" Background="Red">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

And code-behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234238

namespace App1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private ObservableCollection<string> _data = null;

        public ObservableCollection<string> Data
        {
            get { return _data; }
            set
            {
                _data = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        } 

        private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            ObservableCollection<string> newData = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                newData.Add(r.Next(1000).ToString());
            }
            Data = newData;
        }

        public void RaisePropertyChanged()
        {
            var eventHandlers = PropertyChanged;
            if (eventHandlers != null)
            {
                eventHandlers(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Data"));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

When you tap the button on the page several times, you will clearly see, that the first item is animated a bit late (the previous disappears a bit to late and is replaced with the new content visibly later than the other items).

Comment: could you pls provide a sample that illustrate clearly the issue, the transition looks smooth to me !

Comment: Sorry for the delay, the code is now here.